# Update child object in ElasticSearch using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an Elastic Search Document with the following structure:

```
{
   "Id": 123,
   "name": "MyName",
   "skill": {
         "skillId": 321,
         "name": "Skill Name",
         "description": "Skill Description"
    } 
}
```

I also have a class that maps to this document:

```
public class Person {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
      public Skill skill { get; set; }
}

public class Skill{
      public int skillId { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to update the skill description on elastic search:

```
var person = _client.Get(.......)
var newSkill = new Skill();
newSkill.skillId = person.skill.skillId;
newSkill.description = "This is a new Description"

var result = _client.Update<Person, Skill>(u => u
            .IdFrom(person)
            .Doc(newSkill)
            .RetryOnConflict(3)
            .Refresh()
        );
```

This code does not update the existing Skill of the person, instead, it adds the Skill properties to the root of the Person.

So whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use ElasticSearch as if it was SQL.

You need to assign the new `Skill` to the `Person` and update the whole `Person` object as follow:

```
var person = _client.Get(.......)
var newSkill = new Skill();
newSkill.name = "New Skill";
newSkill.description = "This is a new Description"

person.skill = newSkill;

var result = _client.Update<Person, Person>(u => u
            .IdFrom(person)
            .Doc(person)
            .RetryOnConflict(3)
            .Refresh()
        );
```